# How to solve service unit test error: can't read property name of undefined using Jest in NestJS

Tags: typescript, jestjs, nestjs

Service Unit Test Error (NestJS, Jest) - we have QueryRunner and repository and circular dependencies and should mock all of them in the test suit.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
>
> 23 |   constructor(private repository: BusinessRepository) {
> 24 |     this.Record = this.repository.target;
> 25 |     this.entityName = this.repository.metadata.name.toLowerCase();
> |                                                ^
> 26 |   }
> 27 |
> 28 |   findAll(...relations: string[]) {

`OfferService` extends `BusinessService` and `OfferRepository` extends `BusinessRepository`

This is my service.spec.ts:

```
    describe('offer service test', () => {
      let offerService: OfferService;
      let offerRepository: OfferRepository;
      let connection: Connection;
      const qr = {
        manager: {},
      } as QueryRunner;
      const createOfferDto = {
...
      };
      class ConnectionMock {
        createQueryRunner(mode?: 'master' | 'slave'): QueryRunner {
          return qr;
        }
      }
      const mockOfferRepository = () => ({
        create: jest.fn(),
      });
      beforeEach(async () => {
        console.log('beforeach');
        Object.assign(qr.manager, {
          save: jest.fn().mockReturnValue('2'),
        });
        qr.connect = jest.fn();
        qr.release = jest.fn();
        qr.startTransaction = jest.fn();
        qr.commitTransaction = jest.fn();
        qr.rollbackTransaction = jest.fn();
        qr.release = jest.fn();
        const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
          providers: [
            OfferService,
            {
              provide: OfferRepository,
              useFactory: mockOfferRepository,
            },
            {
              provide: Connection,
              useClass: ConnectionMock,
            },
            {
              provide: CartItemService,
              useFactory: () => ({
                getUsersMustBeWorkingNow: jest.fn(() => true),
              }),
            },
          ],
        }).compile();
        offerRepository = await module.get<OfferRepository>(OfferRepository);
        offerService = await module.get<OfferService>(OfferService);
        connection = module.get<Connection>(Connection);
      });
      describe('create', () => {
        it('should be defined', () => {
          expect(offerService).toBeDefined();
        });
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jest is telling you what's missing pretty clearly. Your `mockOfferRepository` object needs to have a `metadata` object with a `name` property that is of type `string`.

```js
const mockOfferRepository = () => ({
  create: jest.fn(),
  metadata: {
    name: 'test_repo'
  },
});
```

Should fix it for you.

Comment: I did that but result didn't changeT yet same error @Jay_McDoniel

Answer (score 0):

You constructor should be calling super() as first statement if there is inheritance.

Comment: super is called,
export class OfferService extends BusinessService<Offer> {
  constructor(
    @Inject(forwardRef(() => CartItemService))
  ) {
    super(offerRepository);
  }

Comment: I cannot see in your test where you provide BusinessRepository, this should be a mock. I don't think that provide OfferRepository will do the trick, you need to provide BusinessRepository

Comment: export class OfferRepository extends BusinessRepository<Offer> {}